# Figuring out size of a symmetry group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

If we have two congruent regular n-gons in the plane, and the symmetry group is the numbers of ways to pick up both of the polygons and put them down so that they cover the same points, what would the size of this group be? I can see that I am supposed to use the result that for a group $G$, we have that $|G| = |G_x||Orb(x)|$ for $x\in G$. I would think that the size of the orbit of any $x$ in $G$ would just be $n$ (I am not sure if that is right). Also for the stabilizer of any $x$, that would be the set of elements that when conjugated with $x$, give you $x$ back, and in this case the only element that I can think that would do that would be the identity, so then would $|G_x|=1$?

Comment: Check out dihedral groups https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group

Comment: @avs yes I see that $D_n$ is the group of symmetries of an n-gon.  I don't see the relation completely. Does the problem statement just boil down to finding $|D_n|$?

Comment: As far as I can tell, picking up both polygons and matching the vertices is equivalent to fixing one of the polygons, and putting the other one on top of the first so as to match the vertices.  If so, yes, the problem is to find $|D_{n}|$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @avs I was thinking about them covering the same finite set of points on the plane, but now that you say that, I relaized you are right. We know that $|D_n|=2n$ so my answer would have been correct if I accounted for flips when calculating the size of the stabilizer.